# What does the "D" command do in sed?

Tags: sed

I have read the [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) manual for the `D` command. There it says:

> D
>
> If pattern space contains no newline, start a normal new cycle as if
>   the d command was issued. Otherwise, delete text in the pattern space
>   up to the first newline, and restart cycle with the resultant pattern
>   space, without reading a new line of input.

But I do not know how to use it.

```
$ seq 5 | sed D
```

The output is nothing.

Comment: some examples can be found here: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-three/

Comment: `sed` is not part of bash -- it's entirely usable from any other shell or with no shell at all, so questions about `sed` shouldn't be in the bash tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's consider four examples.  While only the last two might be considered useful, they all illustrate how `D` works.

By default, sed reads its input and puts one line at a time into the pattern.  Unless one takes a step to add a newline to the pattern space, the pattern space will never have a newline.  In this case, `D` is just like `d` and, consequently, this command produces no output:

```
seq 5 | sed 'D'
```

We can use a substitute command to put a newline into the pattern space. In the following, we add a newline to the pattern space and then the `D` command deletes.  Because there was a newline, `sed` starts the cycle over without reading any input.  Consequently, the following is an infinite loop:

```
seq 5 | sed 's/^/dummy line\n/;p; D'  # Infinite loop
```

Now, let's do something somewhat useful with `D`.  In the example below, we use `N` to read in a new line, causing two lines to be in the pattern space with a newline separating them.  Except on the last line in the input, we ask the `D` command to delete the older line and sed starts the cycle over. As a consequence, the 
following sed command behaves like `tail -2`:

```
$ seq 5 | sed 'N;$!D'   # Like `tail -2`
4
5
```

Lastly, let's extend this to print only the last X lines of a file.  Taking X=5 as an example, the following prints the last 5 lines of the input:

```
$ seq 200 | sed ':a; N; 1,5ba; D'  # Like `tail -5`
196
197
198
199
200
```

The loop `:a; N; 1,5ba` reads in the first 5 lines of the file into the pattern space.  After that, one new line is read by `N` while `D` causes the oldest line in the pattern space to be deleted.  As a result, the pattern space will always have the newest 5 lines.

(Note also that a GNU-specific [feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#N_005fcommand_005flast_005fline) of the `N` command is relied upon there, namely to print the pattern space before exiting on the last line of the file.)

The above commands were all tested under GNU sed.  For BSD sed, expect to make some minor changes to achieve the same results.

Comment: great explanation,But i have a question more,why  note write  seq 5 | sed 'N;$!D'  like  seq 5 | sed 'N;$!Dp',

Comment: @qinpeter `sed 'N;$!Dp'` is not a valid sed command.   Can you clarify what you meant?

Comment: Key point: never actually do this. If you're using `D` or anything else related to hold space or pattern space or any other "space" then you should be using some other tool instead of sed (e.g. the `Like...` tools mentioned in the examples) for clarity, robustness, portability, efficiency, and most other desirable attributes of software. If you think I'm mistaken, post a new question using it in some specific context and asking for a better way to do the job and I'll provide one (as will many others I'm sure).

Comment: @EdMorton When I wrote this answer, I thought of you and, if I had had more time,  I would have preemptively written a comment like that for you.

Comment: Note also that BSD sed just prints the whole file when `':a; N; 1,5ba; D'` is run.

Comment: I just edited in an explanation of why the script `:a; N; 1,5ba; D` actually prints on the last line of the file in GNU sed only.

Comment: @AlexHarvey Thanks for that.  The difference between GNU and BSD sed are often subtle but frustrating.